# Getting a refreshToken from msal using axios interceptor

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to understand the correct way to get a new token from msal when my axios request comes back with a 401 error. I understand how to do it using the axios.interceptors.response.use but for some reason I have 2 issue.

1. Axios error status or event axios error comes back with 0 inside or undefined. The error.message has "Network Error" inside and that's it.
2. How do I fetch a new token since my agent.ts isn't accepting hooks?

Here's my code for the msal part and the axios part

agent.ts

```
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { ICategory, IIncident } from '../models/ApiInterface';

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: https://localhost:7088'
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
});

instance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
    const token = window.sessionStorage
      .getItem('jwt')
      ?.substring(1)
      .slice(0, -1);
    if (token) config.headers!.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response: AxiosResponse) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error: AxiosError) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;

    if (error.message === 'Network Error' || error.response?.status === 401) {
       originalRequest._retry = true;
       const token = await pca.acquireTokenSilent({
         scopes: originalRequest.scopes
       });
       originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      return axios(originalRequest);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
    if (error.message === 'Network Error' || error.response?.status === 401) {
      console.log('This is my new error', error.response);
    }
    throw error.response;
  }
);

const responseBody = (response: AxiosResponse) => response.data;

const requests = {
  get: (url: string) => instance.get(url).then(responseBody),
  post: (url: string, body: {}) => instance.post(url, body).then(responseBody),
  put: (url: string, body: {}) => instance.put(url, body).then(responseBody),
  del: (url: string) => instance.delete(url).then(responseBody),
};

const Incidents = {
  list: (): Promise<IIncident[]> => requests.get('/incidents'),
  new: (): Promise<string> => requests.get('/incidents/new'),
  details: (id: string): Promise<IIncident> => requests.get(`/incidents/${id}`),
  create: (incident: Partial<IIncident>) =>
    requests.post('/incidents', incident),
  update: (incident: IIncident) =>
    requests.put(`/incidents/${incident.id}`, incident),
  delete: (id: string) => requests.del(`/incidents/${id}`),
};

const Categories = {
  list: () => requests.get('/categories'),
  details: (id: string) => requests.get(`/categories/${id}`),
  create: (category: ICategory) => requests.post('/categories', category),
  update: (category: ICategory) =>
    requests.put(`/categories/${category.id}`, category),
  delete: (id: string) => requests.del(`/categories/${id}`),
};

export { Incidents, Categories };
```

AuthContext.tsx

```
import React, {
  useContext,
  createContext,
  useState,
  MouseEventHandler,
  useEffect,
} from 'react';
import { AuthCodeMSALBrowserAuthenticationProvider } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/authCodeMsalBrowser';
import { User } from 'microsoft-graph';
import {
  InteractionRequiredAuthError,
  InteractionType,
  PublicClientApplication,
} from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';

import { getAllAADUsers, getAvatar, getUser } from '../services/GraphService';
import { msalConfig } from '../utils/authConfig';
import useSessionStorage from '../../../hooks/useSessionStorage';

export interface AppApi {
  token?: string;
}

export interface AppUser {
  avatar?: string;
  displayName?: string;
  email?: string;
  id?: string;
  roles?: string | string[];
}

export interface AppError {
  message: string;
  debug?: string;
}

type AppContext = {
  user?: AppUser;
  allADUsers?: User[];
  error?: AppError;
  signIn?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>;
  signOut?: MouseEventHandler<HTMLElement>;
  displayError?: Function;
  clearError?: Function;
  authProvider?: AuthCodeMSALBrowserAuthenticationProvider;
  apiToken?: AppApi;
};

const appContext = createContext<AppContext>({
  user: undefined,
  allADUsers: undefined,
  error: undefined,
  signIn: undefined,
  signOut: undefined,
  displayError: undefined,
  clearError: undefined,
  authProvider: undefined,
  apiToken: undefined,
});

export function useAppContext(): AppContext {
  return useContext(appContext);
}

interface ProvideAppContextProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function ProvideAuthContext({
  children,
}: ProvideAppContextProps) {
  const auth = useProvideAppContext();
  return <appContext.Provider value={auth}>{children}</appContext.Provider>;
}

function useProvideAppContext() {
  const msal = useMsal();
  const [apiToken, setApiToken] = useState<AppApi | undefined>(undefined);
  const [user, setUser] = useState<AppUser | undefined>(undefined);
  const [error, setError] = useState<AppError | undefined>(undefined);
  const [allADUsers, setAllADUsers] = useState<User[] | undefined>(undefined);
  const [_, setValue] = useSessionStorage('jwt', '');

  const displayError = (message: string, debug?: string) => {
    setError({ message, debug });
  };

  const clearError = () => {
    setError(undefined);
  };

  // Used by the Graph SDK to authenticate API calls
  const authProvider = new AuthCodeMSALBrowserAuthenticationProvider(
    msal.instance as PublicClientApplication,
    {
      account: msal.instance.getActiveAccount()!,
      scopes: msalConfig.scopeGraph.scopes,
      interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkUser = async () => {
      if (!user) {
        try {
          // Check if user is already signed in
          const account = msal.instance.getActiveAccount();
          if (account) {
            // Get the user from Microsoft Graph
            const user = await getUser(authProvider);
            const avatar = await getAvatar(authProvider);

            setUser({
              avatar: avatar || '',
              displayName: user.displayName || '',
              email: user.mail || user.userPrincipalName || '',
              id: user.id || '',
              roles: account.idTokenClaims?.roles || '',
            });

            setAllADUsers(await getAllAADUsers(authProvider));

            ///Getting the Api Token if one is needed
            await getApiToken();
          }
        } catch (err: any) {
          displayError(err.message);
        }
      }
    };
    checkUser();
  });

  const signIn = async () => {
    const accounts = await msal.instance.loginPopup({
      scopes: msalConfig.scopeGraph.scopes,
      prompt: 'select_account',
    });
    console.log('signIn');
    //Getting the Api Token if one is needed
    await getApiToken();

    // Get the user from Microsoft Graph
    const user = await getUser(authProvider);
    const avatar = await getAvatar(authProvider);

    setAllADUsers(await getAllAADUsers(authProvider));

    setUser({
      avatar: avatar || '',
      displayName: user.displayName || '',
      email: user.mail || user.userPrincipalName || '',
      id: user.id || '',
      roles: accounts.account?.idTokenClaims?.roles || '',
    });
  };

  const signOut = async () => {
    await msal.instance.logoutPopup();
    setUser(undefined);
    setApiToken(undefined);
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem('jwt');
  };

  const getApiToken = async () => {
    if (msalConfig.scopeAPI.scopes.length > 0) {
      msal.instance
        .acquireTokenSilent({
          scopes: msalConfig.scopeAPI.scopes,
        })
        .then((response) => {
          setValue(response.accessToken);
          setApiToken({
            token: response.accessToken,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
            msal.instance
              .acquireTokenPopup({
                scopes: msalConfig.scopeAPI.scopes,
                prompt: 'select_account',
              })
              .then(function (response) {
                setApiToken({
                  token: response.accessToken,
                });
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
          }
        });
    }
  };

  return {
    user,
    allADUsers,
    error,
    signIn,
    signOut,
    displayError,
    clearError,
    authProvider,
    apiToken,
  };
}
```

PS: It's a React project.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I added to the axios file. I'm not sure it's the way to go but you guys can let me know if it's ok.

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response: AxiosResponse) => {
    return response;
  },
  async (error: AxiosError) => {
    console.log('Intercepted');
    const msal = useMsal();
    const [_, setValue] = useSessionStorage('jwt', '');
    const [isTokenAcquired, setIsTokenAcquired] = useState(false);
    const originalRequest = error.config!;

    const getApiToken = useCallback(async () => {
      if (msalConfig.scopeAPI.scopes.length > 0) {
        msal.instance
          .acquireTokenSilent({
            scopes: msalConfig.scopeAPI.scopes,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            setValue(response.accessToken);
            setIsTokenAcquired(true);
            console.log('Token Acquired');
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
              msal.instance
                .acquireTokenPopup({
                  scopes: msalConfig.scopeAPI.scopes,
                  prompt: 'select_account',
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                  setValue(response.accessToken);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                });
            }
          });
      }
    }, []);

    if (
      !isTokenAcquired &&
      (error.message === 'Network Error' || error.response?.status === 401)
    ) {
      getApiToken();
      return axios(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
```